# Should I be using @Controller classes when doing Spring web flow

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

It seems like I can do everything that the Controller class do inside Spring Web-Flow, for example decision making and switching from page to page. To my understanding, its the C inside the MVC model. Am I correct about this?

So my question is, is there any advantage to still include a Controller class when using Spring Web-Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the request and response, an appropriate design might still include a controller while also having a flow.xml.  For example, if you had this code:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();
```

It's more intelligible to put that in a controller rather than a service.

Also, if you want to register a custom editor, it might make sense to have the controller have this logic in the `initBinder()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Web Flow uses the Spring MVC framework. The DispatcherServlet handles the request. A FlowHandlerMapping is used to map the request to a particular Web Flow.

Web Flow is to solve the problem involved with controller logic that spans multiple-page navigation (a pageflow, or wizard).

Web Flow can eliminate the need for specialized controller classes to accomplish following a path of page transitions/form updates along a predefined workflow. If you don't need to do this, you can save yourself a lot of configuration/complexity just by using MVC.